# RESTEASY throwing exception with empty query params

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, undertow

I have a legacy Tomcat/Jersey based application that we are porting to Undertow/RestEasy, but I am facing an issue with REST calls with empty query params.

Sample resource class:

```
@Path("books")
class BookResource {
    @QueryParam("start") int _start;
    @QueryParam("limit") int _limit;

    @Get
    public List<Books> getBooks {
       //implementation
    }
}
```

With the above resource, when i make a like the one below, it works with my Jersey application, but throws error with RestEasy. I knows this request looks weird, but requests are coming from UI based on user's choice. Could this be a RestEasy configuration?

```
{{baseUrl}}/books?start=&limit=
```

Comment: I solved it by changing start & limit to String and then convert to int if available. But I would still like to know why it was failing in RestEasy.

Answer (score 0):

If query parameters are not defined their value will be null, when it is passed as input to server side service method. As int is primitive and cant hold null values exception is thrown. Changing int to Integer should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, it didn't.